# BLDC motor - strange phase waveforms

Tags: oscilloscope, brushless-dc-motor, driver, waveform

I trying implement bldc motor driver based on below schematic.
The color circles on schematic correspond to waveforms from oscilloscope (all probes are connected to common GND of MCU and PSU that supplies power to motor).
For now I have implemented only switching phases in 150 ms period manner.  The motor is spinning but the rotor jumps by random angle from one commutation to other. I was expecting to get similar behaviour like in stepper motors case (maybe not as precise step as in this kind of motors but regular). Sometimes it looks like the motor is choking. Based on below waveforms can you tell me it is something wrong with the circuit or maybe software?
I implemented switch transistor base on Microchip Application Note: [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00885a.pdf)
I posted switching table from this document below.
I'm wondering why one the Figure 3 there are a lot oscillations? Also the waveforms for phases 1 and 2 do not look trapezoidal like they ought to be, I think.

Figure 1
[image]

Figure 2
[image]

Figure 3
[image]
Figure 4. Zoom in:
[image]

Figure 5
After replace motor with resistors connected in star topology:
[image]

Comment: 100 Ohms is kind of high, no?

Comment: I tried with 47 ohma on all transistors gates but result is the same as above.

Comment: Try it with something like 5 or 10 Ohms. Though I do not expect this to the cause of your issue. It appears you are using sensorless BEMF detection. It's probably due to your algorithm being unable to handle noise (or sampling at the wrong time). You may need some form of signal conditioning or filtering.